# How do I delete these types of recent searches in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, search, history

I really tried googling things such as "how to delete recent searches on google chrome" but I can't find any results. I have a very low vocabulary. So how do I delete these? [Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVoOV.png)

Answer (score 0):

To delete one suggestion from the list :

- Hover the mouse cursor over the suggestion : Its background color will change
- Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
- The suggestion is now deleted.

---

To delete multiple suggestions,
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to enter the history,
place a check-mark next to all the suggestions and hit "Delete"/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @harrymc's answer, the suggestions also include your bookmarks.

If the suggestion is not disappearing after trying to remove it using <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd>, have a look at your bookmarks. You can either remove or rename them.